# extract names from a header file (string operation)

Tags: c++, extract, file-handling

Unable to find the error:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("a.h");

    vector<vector<string>> vect;
  
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line) )
        {
            vector<string> temp;
            if (line.substr(0, line.find(" ")) == (string)"int"){
                temp.push_back(line.substr(line.find(" ")+1));
            }
            if (line[0] == '}' && line[line.size()-1] == ';')
            {
                string string_temp = line.substr(1, line.size()-1);

                cout << string_temp << endl;

                temp.insert(temp.begin(), string_temp);
                vect.push_back(temp);
                temp.clear();
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file"; 
  
    for(auto t : vect){
        for(string s : t){
            cout << s << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I need to extract the structure name and the member names from a `.h` file;
where `a.h` looks like this:

```cpp
typedef struct{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
}struct_req1_t;

 typedef struct{
  int d;
   int e;
   int f;
 }struct_rsp1_t;

 typedef struct{
    int g;
    int h;
    int i;
 }struct_req1_t;
```

I'm thinking of extracting the names as a 2D vector:

```
structure_name1 member1 member2 member3
structure_name2 member1 member2 member3
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you get compiler error? Please copy and paste it into your question. Does it not produce the desired output? Please provide current output.

Comment: If you are implementing a .h parser, why not use an existing one: https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter or libclang?

Comment: Think a.h file as a text file and I have to perform string and file operations to get the names into a 2D vector

Comment: Lots of mistakes in this code. Your loop is not accounting for the fact that the lines that have an `int` field *begin* with whitespace, so `line.find(" ")` will return an index before the `int`, thus `line.substr(0, line.find(" ")) == (string)"int"` will always be false. Or the fact that some lines are blank, thus `if (line[0] == '}' && line[line.size()-1] == ';')` for those lines will be *undefined behavior*. Or the fact that `line.substr(1, line.size()-1)` should be using `line.size()-2` instead to omit the trailing `;` from the extracted `string`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [cppast](https://github.com/foonathan/cppast) : it will provide you with the Abstract Syntax Tree and you should be able to extract any information from any header file.
I successully used it to create a remote code generator.